# Access ASYNC_OPTIONS value in DynamicModule's registerAsync method

Tags: nestjs

```
export class UppUserModule extends UserModuleClass {
    static register(options: typeof OPTIONS_TYPE): DynamicModule {
        const module = super.register(options);
        if (options.useFoo) {
            module.controllers.push(FooController);
        }
        return module;
    }

    static registerAsync(options: typeof ASYNC_OPTIONS_TYPE): DynamicModule {
        const module = super.registerAsync(options);
        //How to access options.useFoo
        return module;
    }
}
```

there is a DynamicModule like above, in `register` method we can access options useFoo value and dynamic push a controller. bu in the `registerAsync` method, we can's access any value but useFactory method. How can we make `registerAsync` method like `register` method?